# How bad is it to have unused operations floating about?

Tags: tensorflow

It would make my code easier to generate a bunch of operations even though they are not used.

Does having unused operations in the graph have a non-negligible impact on performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TensorFlow executes only the ops necessary to get result requested by user so it's safe to leave unused operations in graph.

Note that there's a 2GB limit on size of graph, so if you add too many unused ops, you may hit this error.

Comment: Do the unused ops take away memory and cause out of memory errors? 
Say i have many ops for testing my model, that I want to run every 1k steps. Can these ops cause an out of memory error for training ?